# Uni Project Feedback and soundcloud giveaway

Tags: feedback, design, music, composition

Hey everyone!

So I have finished the creative project that I posted earlier. You can view it here - [The Arrival on Vimeo](http://vimeo.com/36180836).

I am looking for constructive feedback on the project, and to show my appreciation I am giving away either a Soundcloud Premium account or $20 iTunes gift card. The winner will be picked by random and the draw will include anyone who offers me constructive feedback, drawn on the 9th Feb, 1pm AEST.

I have created sound and music for a graphic novel that I scanned and turned into video.

I aim to create a soundtrack that is reflective of the book's visual style and shows the world from the character's point of view, using an appropriate balance of abstract and descriptive sound.

It features artwork from Shaun Tan's graphic novel, The Arrival - [shauntan.net](http://shauntan.net)

I appreciate any feedback you can offer as it is an essential element of my project.

Thanking you in advance,
Eric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing soon! I guess it's not that big a prize is it. Next time I will make it a better prize to attract more feedback.

Answer (score 2):

I would echo what has been said lovely graphics and sound design I would also agree about the opening crowd sound. As a more general point and this might be stylistic decision, but I felt the pacing of the video and sound could be varied for emphasis and dramatic effect. Perhaps distinguish between functional frames and emotionally significant frames in the story. This would allow you to give the 'story' more richness. It also allows the viewer/listener more time to enjoy and linger over your great sounds and graphics. Hope that helps. Good work! Best of luck. S

Comment: @Simon thankyou for your feedback. You are right, now that I look at it, some sections do feel a bit rushed. I think when he first enters the balloon it could slow down a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

imo very very cool, loved everything, and music too. the only thing i would change if it was my work, is the "crowd" ambience at the beginning, it doesn't fit kinda...but that's only my opinion, other than that, its very nice :)

Comment: @Linas it's funny I have listened to that crowd ambience so many times that I have lost all objectivity. Thanks for pointing it out.